# Does not android sqlite auto_vacuum truncate whole freelist pages?

Tags: android, sqlite, vacuum

I got two mmssms.db files from SAMSUNG Glaxy and Huawei C8812 respectively. Running "PRAGMA auto_vacuum;" on these files will give result "1" both. But when I had opened these files using hex editor, I found that the ptrmap pages in these file have freelist page records. Then I pulled these files from devices again, after some sms delete operation. I could found freelist page records in ptrmap pages still. The document says that when the auto-vacuum mode is 1 or "full", the freelist pages are moved to the end of the database file and the database file is truncated to remove the freelist pages at every transaction commit. How does these freelist page records and freelist pages remained?

Comment: What are ptrmap pages?